# How can I clean up this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have this jQuery code that I wrote to load a plugin I've been developing.

I'm fairly new to this so this question might seem a little basic but I just can't get my head around how to clean up this code? Is there a way to reduce this into something a little lighter?

Basically 'a' shows the div (target) and .mv, .sb & .sl are all classes of 'a' tags. Depending on which link is click will depend on what displays (the spot_id changes the data loaded from the plugin).

The code works fine but I'm sure there's an easier way to write this. Thanks in advance!

```
$('a').click(function () {
    $(this).attr("href");
});

$('.mv').click(function () {
    $(this).surfplugin({
        spot_id: 1
    });
});

$('.sb').click(function () {
    $(this).surfplugin({
        spot_id: 2
    });
});

$('.sl').click(function () {
    $(this).surfplugin({
        spot_id: 3
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
    <ul class="nav">
                <li class="mavericks">
                    <a href="#display" class="mv">Mavericks</a>
                </li>
                <li class="santa-barbara">
                    <a href="#display" class="sb">Santa Barbara</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#display" class="sl">Steamer Lane</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <div class="content">
            <section id="display" class="beach"></section>
        </div>
```

Comment: Code looks relatively clean to me...4 handlers, minimal things going on.

Comment: Err, `$('a').click(function(){
  $(this).attr("href");
 });` doesn't actually do anything?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`[data-*]` attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) to store the data you're passing to the plugin, and use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to access the autocasted value of the `[data-*]` attribute. [It's possible that you may want to use `.attr()` in some instances to prevent autocasting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262427/497418).

I will assume the following HTML as it wasn't provided:

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<a href="..." class="mv" data-spot-id="1">...</a>
<a href="..." class="sb" data-spot-id="2">...</a>
<a href="..." class="sl" data-spot-id="3">...</a>
```

<sub>JS:</sub>

```
$('[data-spot-id]').on('click', function () {
    $(this).surfplugin({
        spot_id: $(this).data('spotId')
    });
});
```

Alternatively, if you have more configuration options to pass to `surfplugin`, you could have the `[data-*]` attribute contain JSON:

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<a href="..." data-surfplugin='{"spot_id":1,"foo":"bar baz"}'>...</a>
```

<sub>JS:</sub>

```
$('[data-surfplugin]').on('click', function () {
    $(this).surfplugin($(this).data('surfplugin'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The usefulness of this is debatable, as you've only three callbacks, but you can use a simple mapping of elements to "spot id"s:

```
var spots = [];
spot[1] = '.mv';
spot[2] = '.sb';
spot[3] = '.s1';

for (var i = 0; i < spot && spot[i]; ++i) {
  (function (i) {
    $(spots[i]).click(function () {
      $(this).surfplugin({ spot_id: i });
    });
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an html5 data-attribute to reduce the code to something like this;

```
$('.mv,.sl,.sb').click(function () {
    $(this).surfplugin({
        spot_id: $(this).attr('data-spot_id');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var selectors = ['.mv', '.sb', '.sl'];
$(selectors.join(', ')).on('click', function() {
    $(this).surfplugin({
        spot_id: selectors.indexOf('.'+this.getAttribute('class')) + 1 
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about... (work when only single class)

```
$(document).on('click','.mv, .sb, .sl',function () {
    var class = $(this).attr('class');
    var list = ['mv','sb','sl'];
    var i = $.inArray(class,list);
        i = i!==-1?i+1:false;
    if(i) {
        $(this).surfplugin({spot_id:i});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another twisted suggestion :

```
$('.mv,.sb,.sl').click(function () {
    var $el = $(this),
        re = /(^|\s)(mv|sb|sl)(\s|$)/,
        cls = $el.attr('class').match(re)[2],
        map = { mv: 1, sb: 2, sl: 3 };
    $el.surfplugin({
        spot_id: map[cls]
    });
});
```